# Serial.read() fall into error after some times

Tags: python, pyserial, rfid

I'm trying to read RFID cards with an RFID card reader plugged in USB on my raspi 3b+

Here is my code

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty1', 115200)
    while True:
        incomingByte = ser.read(10)
        print(incomingByte.decode())
        ser.flushInput()
        
    ser.close()
```

When I scan a card, here is the output

```
0002429021
```

Which is what I expect. But after some time (few seconds) I have the following error message

```
line 45, in main
    incomingByte = ser.read(10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 595, in read
    raise SerialException(
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

So I've looked around and tried many things:

- run raspi-config and under interfaces turn on serial, turn off console
- Edit /boot/config.txt and add the line enable_uart=1
- In /boot/cmdline.txt remove the references to console
- Disabled getty `sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@USB0.service`

I've tried alternate codes:

**1/ with try...except
**

```
try:
   incomingByte = ser.read(10)
   print(incomingByte.decode())
   ser.flushInput()
except Exception:
   pass
```

==> I can read 1 card then the program get stuck (no errors but no more scan possible, prompt is stuck)

**2/ with inwaiting() + try...except**

```
while True:
  while (ser.inWaiting()>0):
     try:
       incomingByte = ser.read(10)
       print(incomingByte.decode())
       ser.flushInput()
  except (OSError, serial.serialutil.SerialException):
       print("No data this time")
        
ser.close()
```

It outputs

```
No data this time
002429021
```

then the following error

```
line 549, in in_waiting
    s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

**Note:**
One of the main difference I see with many other people with similar code is that my rfid card reader is reachable on `/dev/tty1` where I usually see `/dev/ttyS1` or `/dev/ttyAMA0` or `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyACM0`

I don't really know what's the difference between all of that but maybe it has an impact.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Stack Overflow asks to say what we've tried to solve, that's what I did :P The specific problem is that it falls into an error after some time